# Equality of inner measure and outer measure for complete measure space

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(\Omega,F, \mu)$ be a measure space, and let $F_{\mu}$ be the completion of $F$ relative to $\mu$. If $A \subset \Omega$, define:

$\mu_{0}(A)=\sup \{\mu(B: B \in F, B\subset A \}$,        $\mu^{0}(A)=\inf \{\mu(B: B \in F, B\supset A \}$.

a) If $A \in F_{\mu}$, show that $\mu_{0}(A)=\mu^{0}(A)=\mu(A)$.

b) Conversely, if $\mu_{0}(A)=\mu^{0}(A)< \infty$, show that $A \in F_{\mu}$.

for the part (a), based on definition it is obvious that $\mu_{0}(A)\le \mu^{0}(A)$. but I don't know how to prove $\mu_{0}(A)\ge \mu^{0}(A)$.
Also, I would appreciate if you could help me with part (b).

Comment: What is **your** definition of the completion of a $\sigma$-algebra w.r.t. a measure?

Comment: @PhoemueX The Completion of a measure space $(\Omega , F, \mu )$ is defined as follows. Let $F_{\mu}$ be the class of sets $A \cup   N$, where $A$ ranges over $F$ and $N$ over all subsets of sets of measure $0$ in $F$